# How to update server resource using WebDAV

Tags: android, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am writing an Android application in which I am using Jackrabbit WebDAV Library.

With help of this WebDAV library, I can download and upload files from and to server. This works as expected.

Now I want to get a byte array from file with specific offset from the server. For this what I have tried is:

```
byte buffer[] = null;
Log.d(TAG, "downloadBytes '" + fileUri + "'  byteOffset '" + byteOffset + "'  byteOffset '" + byteCount);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

GetMethod httpMethod = new GetMethod(fileUri);

httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
int total = byteOffset + byteCount;
String bytesMessage = "bytes=" + byteOffset + "-" + total;
Log.d(TAG, "bytesMessage " + bytesMessage);

httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Range", bytesMessage);
httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");

httpClient.executeMethod(httpMethod);
```

This works as expected.

Similarly, I want to update file on server with byte array by specifying offset, but this doesn't appear to work; the server returns a 400 Bad Request error code.

```
byte buffer[] = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x50};
Log.d(TAG, "downloadBytes '" + fileUri + "'  byteOffset '" + byteOffset + "'  byteCount '" + byteCount);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();


PutMethod httpMethod = new PutMethod(fileUri);

httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
int total = byteOffset + byteCount;
String bytesMessage = "bytes=" + byteOffset + "-" + total;
Log.d(TAG, "bytesMessage " + bytesMessage);

httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Range", bytesMessage);
httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Overwrite", "T");

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
RequestEntity requestEntity = new InputStreamRequestEntity(is, "text/plain");
httpMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);

httpClient.executeMethod(httpMethod);
```

What am I missing in the request header?

Answer (score 0):

Following are correct headers, using this I am able update webdav server resources with offset and byte length.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        PutMethod httpMethod = new PutMethod(fileUri);
        httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        int total = byteOffset + byteCount;
        int range = total-1;

        String rangeMessage = "bytes=" + byteOffset +"-" + range;
        Log.d(TAG, "rangeMessage " + rangeMessage);

        String lengthMessage = Integer.toString(byteCount);
        String contentRangeMessage = "bytes " + byteOffset +"-" + range + "/*";

        Log.d(TAG, "contentRangeMessage " + contentRangeMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "lengthMessage " + lengthMessage);

        httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Length", lengthMessage);
        httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Range", contentRangeMessage);
        httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Overwrite", "T");
```